# dovecot v1 "ST" tagged files removing via command line

Tags: dovecot

Is it ok to write a little script to just remove dovecot v1 emails marked seen & deleted files (ending ST)? Or do they have to be purged through mail client?

I have a customer that is using outlook & they have been just getting flagged for the last number of years & are taking up a lot of space. They are afraid to click a mouse let alone walk through a purge.

If can do myself would be sweet.

Answer (score 0):

`dovecot` in general is not restrictive for file manipulations. Version 2+ has a tool named `doveadm` that can be used in most cases. But direct operations are ok too. You can run something like that to delete all the files having flags set to `ST`:

```
find /var/mail -type f -name *:*,*ST -exec rm {} +
```

Complicated pattern is used to avoid the friendly fire on the plain files matching the `*ST` pattern.

It is also good idea to delete all the dovecot's index files in the mailboxes. If absent dovecot recreate them on the next access but without mention of all the purged files.